# Want Actionbar, but not holo theme skin

Tags: android, android-layout, themes, actionbarsherlock

`Theme.Holo` does not look good with my current background, and `Theme.Black` looks much better.  Is it possible to use only the `Theme.Holo` heading (actionbar), and have a normal black layout?  How would i go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"` for your application.

That's how it looks:

[image: Default Sherlock Theme]